# Use Realm Relation List<Object> UITable View

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to use a relationship object from Realm on a UITableView in Swift 2 latests version. My objects are as follows...

```
class Incident : Object {
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    let notes : List<Comment> = List<Comment>()
}

class Comment : Object {
    dynamic var note = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
}
```

In my UITableView I can correctly add and remove Comments to the Incident notes list and print the entire Incident object but I dont know how to fill the table view with the contents of the List propery. I checked the Realm.io site for information on this but the methods outlined there apparently are outdated. I tried using

```
var theNotes : Result<Comment> = myIncidentObject.notes.sorted("createdAt")
```

But I get the following exception.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   'This method can only be called on RLMArray instances retrieved from
>   an RLMRealm'

Any assistance on how to implement this or how to troubleshoot it is really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error describes, you can use [`sorted(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift7Results6sortedu__Rdq_CS_6Objectqd__Ss12SequenceTypezqqqd__S2_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7ElementVS_14SortDescriptor_FGS0_q__Fqd__GS0_q__) only on persisted objects. As long as your `Incident` is not yet added to the Realm, you would need to fall back to the standard library ([`sort`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FeRq_Ss12SequenceTypeqqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7ElementSs10Comparable_SsS_4sortuRq_S_qqq_S_9GeneratorS0_7ElementS1__Fq_FT_GSaqqq_S_9GeneratorS0_7Element_)). Alternatively you can add your `Incident` to the Realm. Be aware though that any modifications you make to it after that must happen from a write transaction.

Comment: Will mark it as correct, I ended up using UUIDs to link objects and to easily sync them on a web api. Thanks a lot.